# Laravel relationship with two tables [something like union]

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have two tables: **wishlist** and **products**
I want to read products table according to **product_id** in wishlist table but for specific user...

First from wishlist table I read columns with **user_id** which would be equall to logged in user id (**Auth::user()->id**)... When that is done, I read products table with **product_id** from wishlist table which would be same as **id** in products...

**Controller:**

```
public function getWhishlist() {
    $wishItems = WishItem::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
    return View::make('wishlist')->with('wishItems', $wishItems);
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach ($wishItems as $wishItem)
    {{ dd($wishItem) }}
    <?php $getProducts = Product::find($wishItem->product_id); ?>
    @foreach ($getProducts as $getProduct)
        {{ $getProduct->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Model:**

```
class WishItem extends Eloquent {
     protected $table = 'wishlist';
}
```

**{{ dd($wishItem) }}** -> nothing happens
and nothing happens at all with whole code... there is no any results from table

My question is how to read from two tables??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually fetching anything.

Try this

```
$wishItems = WishItem::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-webshop\laravel\app\views\wishlist.blade.php)

Comment: Can you show the output of wishItems vardump from your controller?

Comment: From the var dump it is visiable you can get $wishItem->product_id; `Product::find($wishItem->product_id)->get();` add get method to this and try.